# Flask Windows Apache issues

Tags: python, windows, apache, flask

I'm attempting to get Flask running off apache on windows and I'm coming across the error message below.  Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Error Message:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=4380): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/I4/importicus/importicus.wsgi'.
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]   File "C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\flask-0.9-py2.6.egg\\flask\\app.py", line 1701, in __call__
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]   File "C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\flask-0.9-py2.6.egg\\flask\\app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]     response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]   File "C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\flask-0.9-py2.6.egg\\flask\\app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]   File "C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\flask-0.9-py2.6.egg\\flask\\app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]   File "C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\flask-0.9-py2.6.egg\\flask\\app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]   File "C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\flask-0.9-py2.6.egg\\flask\\app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Fri Nov 30 14:47:47 2012] [error] [client 192.168.100.109] TypeError: application() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

my WSGI file looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "c:\i4\importicus")

from importicus import importicus_main as application
application.debug = True
```

and my application file looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,jsonify, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import importicus_functions
import ast, os, sys
importicus_main = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
TEMPLATE_FOLDER = 'templates'
importicus_main.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
importicus_main.config['TEMPLATE_FOLDER'] = TEMPLATE_FOLDER



@importicus_main.route('/')
def application(environ, start_response):
        status = '200 OK'
        output = "Hello World! INSIDE"
        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                            ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [output]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is you're trying to write WSGI, not Flask. (Flask is WAY easier.)

This is what you want:

```
@importicus_main.route('/')
def application():
  return "Hello World! INSIDE"
```

Controllers (like the application function) don't take parameters, unless there are parameters in your url string. An example would be:

```
# /blog/1 would be a valid URL here
@importicus_main.route('/blog/<int:post_id>')
def blog_post(post_id):
  return "This would be blog post number %s" % post_id
```

Take a look at the Flask tutorial if you skipped it - it's excellent. I'd also suggest getting your app running with the built-in test server. You can easily port to mod_wsgi (or whatever) later.

Comment: Excellent, it seems I had changed too many things in my haste to get it running on our server.  I've been developing in Flask for the last 6 months or so, but this is the first deployment (and of course it all went horribly wrong from the get go). Thanks!